# Spring-boot, Angular14, google sign in Integration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, google-oauth, angular14

I'm trying to integrate google-Oauth2 spring Boot and Angular.
I'm calling the google sigin from angular and after getting the idToken I'm passing it to my springBoot app to the login endpoint there I am generating the accessToken and refreshToken after verifying details from the idToken, For other API endpoints I'm adding a custom filter to verify the accessToken , is this a secure way or is there any better way to do it? I'm attaching the files

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig {
    
        @Autowired
        private JwtFilter jwtFilter;
    
        @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
            FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
            bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
            return bean;
        }
        @Bean
        public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                    .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                    .authorizeHttpRequests(auth ->auth
                            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
                            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    
                    )
                    .addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                    ;
    
            return http.build();
        }
    
    }
```

JwtFilter

```
@Component
    public class JwtFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    
        @Autowired
        private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    
        @Autowired
        private JwtRefreshUtil jwtRefreshUtil;
    
        private final RequestMatcher ignoredPaths = new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/login");
    
    
        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                        FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            System.out.println(httpServletRequest);
            if (this.ignoredPaths.matches(httpServletRequest)) {
                filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
                return;
            }
            String authorizationHeader = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
            String path = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();
            String token = null;
            if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                token = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
            }
            if (path.equals("/api/user/refreshAuthToken")) {
                    if (jwtRefreshUtil.validateRefreshToken(token)) {
                         SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(jwtRefreshUtil.extractAllClaims(token),null,null));
                    }
            } else {
                    if (jwtUtil.validateToken(token)) {
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(jwtUtil.extractAllClaims(token),null,null));
                    }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, httpServletResponse);
        }
    }
```

userAuthController

```
@RestController
    @RequestMapping("/auth")
    public class UserAuthController extends BaseController {
    
        @Autowired
        private UserAuthService userAuthService;
        @PostMapping
        @RequestMapping("/login")
        public ResponseEntity<AppResponse<TokenDto>> login(HttpServletRequest request){
            AppResponse<TokenDto> myResponse = new AppResponse<>();
            try {
                TokenDto tokenDto=userAuthService.login(request.getHeader("Authorization"));
                handleObjectSuccess(myResponse,tokenDto);
            } catch (InvoiceAutomationException ex) {
                handleAPIError(myResponse,ex, ErrorCodes.USER_NOT_FOUND);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                handleAPIError(myResponse,ex,ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR);
            }
            return ResponseEntity.ok(myResponse);
        }
    }
```

UserAuthServiceImpl

```
@Service
    public class UserAuthServiceImpl implements UserAuthService{
    
        @Autowired
        private GoogleTokenService googleTokenService;
    
        @Autowired
        private ZohoService zohoService;
    
        @Autowired
        private JwtUtil jwtUtil;
    
        @Autowired
        private JwtRefreshUtil jwtRefreshUtil;
    
        @Override
        public TokenDto login(String idToken) {
            TokenDto tokenDto=new TokenDto();
            try{
                String email=googleTokenService.verifyToken(idToken);
                if(email!=null){
                    ZohoEmployeeDto employeeDetails = zohoService.getEmployeeDetails(email);
                    tokenDto.setAccessToken(jwtUtil.createToken(employeeDetails.toHashMap(),employeeDetails.getEmailID()));
                    tokenDto.setRefreshToken(jwtRefreshUtil.createToken(employeeDetails.toHashMap(),employeeDetails.getEmailID()));
                }
            }catch (InvoiceAutomationException ex) {
                throw new InvoiceAutomationException(ErrorCodes.USER_NOT_FOUND,"employee not found");
            }
            return tokenDto;
        }
    }
```

my Spring boot version is

```
<parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.9</version>
            <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

I'm new to spring security, is this a good way or is there any better way to do this?

How to handle this to ensure security